# Release Management - Continuous Integration

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, application-pool, release-management, ms-release-management

I've configured Release Management to pick up when source is checked in and deploy the code.  However, I am having a problem:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Package location "\devserver1\Drop\Release Manager Build (Continuous)\Release Manager Build (Continuous)_20140115.15_PublishedWebsites\FrontEnd_Package" does not exists or Application Pool user does not have access. at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Common.Helpers.FileTransferer.CopyFolder(String sourceFolder, String destFolder) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Services.DeploymentControllerService.GetPackageFileInfos(String packageLocation) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The strange thing is that if I simply open up Release Management tool, go to the failed deployment and click "retry deployment" it works first time no problem.

I have tried giving "Everyone", "TFSService" & "ReleaseManagement" users full permissions to both the drop folder and the build folder but still it doesn't work.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that because I didn't have a "Configuration" set up in my build process, nothing was created as there was no default either.  Once I created this it seemed to work.
My discussion with Microsoft here:
[MSDN:Release Management - Continuous Integration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5485d8a9-c4d7-47ec-957e-ddeda94bceb9/release-management-continuous-integration?forum=tfsbuild)

Answer (score 0):

I had to give "Network Service" explicit permission to the drop folder.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that will help someone else, but for me I already had that and I found the problem I had.